# Transaction receipt contains all log entries, but only the last two are decoded by web3

Tags: web3js, transactions, events

I have a flow which yields 4 events.

When I obtain the transaction hash via web3.js, I can see that all 4 events are included in the receipt logs, but only the last 2 events are in the decoded logs (which means I have to decode the first 2 events myself):

```
{
    "receipt": {
        ...
        "logs": [
            {
                "logIndex": 0,
                ...
            },
            {
                "logIndex": 1,
                ...
            },
            {
                "logIndex": 2,
                ...
            },
            {
                "logIndex": 3,
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    "logs": [
        {
            "logIndex": 2,
            ...
        },
        {
            "logIndex": 3,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: It might be helpful if you more fully explained the flow you mention. My guess it there is something in the flow (outside of web3) that's causing this, but without context, it's hard to tell. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush: I can add my on-chain side  (Solidity code), but I think it would just be TMI. From web3, I am invoking a contract function which calls another contract function, etc. At the end of this flow, there are 4 events generated. The `receipt` part shows it clearly, but the decoded-log part contains only partial information. When I run similar flows with only 2 events, all of them are decoded. Perhaps there's a web3 limitation on the amount of decoded events, but it clearly feels like an issue on web3 side. Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you tried the gitter channel?

Comment: @ThomasJayRush: You mean, ask it on GitHub?

Comment: @ThomasJayRush: I think I've got the answer, see below.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I understand the reason:

All the events generated during the execution of the function called by web3 are included in the receipt logs, but only the events generated **in the scope of the contract in which the function is implemented** are included in the decoded logs.

For example, given the following on-chain code:

**File `IContract1.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface IContract1 {
    function func(uint256 x) external returns (uint256);
}
```

**File `Contract1.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import "./IContract1.sol";

contract Contract1 is IContract1{
    event Event1(uint256 x);
    function func(uint256 x) external returns (uint256) {
        Event1(x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

**File `Contract2.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import "./IContract1.sol";

contract Contract2 {
    IContract1 private contract1;
    function Contract2(IContract1 _contract1) public {
        contract1 = _contract1;
    }
    event Event2(uint256 x);
    function func(uint256 x) external returns (uint256) {
        Event2(x);
        return contract1.func(x);
    }
}
```

If I execute the following off-chain code:

```
let contract1 = await artifacts.require("Contract1.sol").new();
let contract2 = await artifacts.require("Contract2.sol").new(contract1.address);

let hash = await contract2.func(42);
```

Then `hash.receipt.logs` will include both `Event1` and `Event2`.

But `hash.logs` will include only `Event2`.