# Event suddenly disapears when i call another function in my contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, events

So i am doing a factory for an ERC20 token contract, here is my factory code:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.4.0 < 0.6.0;

import "./ERC20.sol";
import "./ERC20Interface.sol";

contract Factory {
    address[] createdContract;
    mapping (address => uint256) contractNo;
    mapping (address => address) contractOwner;
    mapping (address => bool) isEIP20;
    address owner;

    event NewContractCreated(address newContractAddress, address contractCreator);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createNewContract() payable public returns(address) {
        ERC20 newContract = new ERC20();

        newContract.EIP20();
        createdContract.push(address(newContract));
        isEIP20[address(newContract)] = true;
        contractNo[msg.sender]++;
        contractOwner[address(newContract)] = msg.sender;

        emit NewContractCreated(address(newContract), msg.sender);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, address _contractAddress)  public returns (bool) {
        ERC20Interface contractUsed = ERC20Interface(_contractAddress);
        require(contractUsed.transfer(_to, 50));
        return true;
    }

    function ownedContract() public view returns(uint256) {
        return contractNo[msg.sender];
    }

    function ownerOfContract(address _contractAddress) public view returns(address) {
        return contractOwner[_contractAddress];
    }
}
```

then i deploy it on ganache test rpc using truffle, then i create a new ERC20 from the factory contract and then check for NewContractCreated event and it fine, it return the result i was expecting:
[image: Event 1]

then i call transfer function from factory contract, then see the NewContractCreated event again but i got empty as a result:
[image: Event 2]

So where did all my past event from before go, and how did it disapear?

Comment: Check [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/48335/16043).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if somebody will get into this kind of problem but the solution to my problem is when using web3js i just have to type `MyContract.getPastEvent("MyEvent", {fromBlock: 0})` 
and it will print out for all event. Don't know how this work but it just work

Comment: When you use fromBlock:0, it will show all the events from the first block.